# Having an Ajax.ActionLink without text (showed as a jQuery button with only one icon)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I use the following ajax ActionLink method.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "RemovePerson", "General", new { PersonId = item.PersonId }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure?", HttpMethod = "Delete", OnSuccess = "JsonDelete_OnSuccess" }, new { @class = "PersonRemove" }) 

$().ready(function () {
    $(".PersonRemove").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash"} });
})
```

The result is showed bellow:

[image]

As you can see, the linkText parameter is " ". I don't want any text in my button. Only one icon. I didn't found any other solution for having an ajax ActionLink without text but I'm not very satisfied with it. I need some advise about it.

**Is there a better solution** than having this ActionLink with the first parameter as " " ?

I would prefer something like:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(null, ....
```

But it doesn't work. I got the error *"Value cannot be null or empty"*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, that's annoying. You could write a custom MyActionLink helper:

```
public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, 
    string actionName, 
    string controllerName, 
    object routeValues, 
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, 
    object htmlAttributes
)
{
    return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(
        " ", 
        actionName, 
        controllerName, 
        routeValues, 
        ajaxOptions, 
        htmlAttributes
    );
}
```

and then:

```
@Ajax.MyActionLink(
    "RemovePerson", 
    "General", 
    new { 
        PersonId = item.PersonId 
    }, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        Confirm = "Are you sure?", 
        HttpMethod = "Delete", 
        OnSuccess = "JsonDelete_OnSuccess" 
    }, 
    new { @class = "PersonRemove" }
)
```

Comment: Yes I could. So you agree with me that using Ajax.ActionLink(" ",... is not very elegant? I'm always looking for a nice way of doing. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Darin. So in fact in this solution we simply 'moved' the problem of " " in a custom helper but the " " is still there... hided. So this is an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Bronzato, yes, to me this is an acceptable solution. We no longer have to repeat the `" "` in every view in which we want to generate a link. We have externalized this into a reusable helper.

Answer (score 0):

The action link indeed does not allow empty strings as a text parameter.

A quick fix, really nasty imho, could be to add the following javascript after the .button() call :

```
$(".PersonRemove .ui-button-text").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It seems also a good alternative but I was not able to use it. I try and my jQuery button lost all except the icon !? But I tried with empty() and this time it works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to define a style with text-indent equals to -9999px. This hides the text. For example:

```
a.settingsButton 
{
    position:absolute;
    width:95px;
    height:95px;
    background:url(images/settingsButton.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none; 
    top:20px;
    left:125px;
    text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```